# Why in my custom TreeView Control, the children of TreeViewItems are not displayed by clicking of any TreeViewItem?

Tags: wpf, templates

```
<TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="BurlyWood">
                            <Image Height="16" Width="16" 
                                   Source="/WpfApplication27;component/Images/Forward.png"></Image>
                            <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"></Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                        IsItemsHost="True" Margin="4,6" Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
```

Comment: You might be able to solve this by using a HierarchicalDataTemplate

Answer (score 0):

By setting the control template you completely overwrote the existing one, and your template no longer contains a button that allows the expansion of the sub-tree, etc.
Templating TreeViewItems is comparatively complex, see [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788727.aspx) for a reference.